# Python Copying Files

Tags: python, file-io, recursion, copy

I have a list of files [input1.txt,input2.txt,input3.txt]

I want to create a new file called input.txt

Then I want to recursively make input.txt be a clone of input1.txt, then 2 then 3

How would I do this?

Comment: Cheesery, since you may not know, it's good etiquette on Stack Overflow to "accept" answers that have solved your question. To do this, go back through your old questions, and click the check mark next to the most helpful answer. This lets others know what solved your problem, plus it awards reputation to the person who took the time to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html)

```
import shutil

def recwrite(filelist):
    if len(filelist) > 0:
        shutil.copyfile(filelist[0], "input.txt")
        recwrite(filelist[1:])
```

It doesn't make any sense to do it recursively though, it would be much quicker to do it iteratively:

```
import shutil

filelist = ["input1.txt","input2.txt","input3.txt"]
for filename in filelist:
    shutil.copyfile(filename,"input.txt")
```